# sqlldr test for number format

Tags: numbers, format, sql-loader

I am loading data into Oracle 12c using sqlldr using a CTL file as below :

```
OPTIONS (rows=1000, bindsize=100000, readsize=100000, silent=header,feedback)
load data
CHARACTERSET UTF8
insert into table TABLEA
fields terminated by '^' optionally enclosed by ','
trailing nullcols
(
NAME,
VOLUME "decode(:VOLUME,null,0,to_number(:VOLUME,'9999999999D999'))",
TEXT
)
```

I am facing difficulty when the number field VOLUME defined in table as NUMBER(13,3) comes in different formats.

```
ABCD^1089.830^CIQ
ABCD^1,089.830^CIQ
ABCD^1.089,830^CIQ
```

Is there a way to load all three formats of number field in field 2 above using sqlldr ?

Expected value in the table is 1089.830 for the all three cases .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tad ugly but it should work. It assumes your volume value data will always have 3 decimal points and the decimal symbol will be a period (based on your number format).  First pass removes all region-specific characters, then second pass puts the period in 3 places from the end:

```
...
VOLUME decimal external "regexp_replace(regexp_replace(:VOLUME, '[\.,]', ''), '([0-9]+)([0-9]{3})', '\\1.\\2')",
...
```

You may not need the "decimal external", try it without and see.

Comment: Thanks , it was helpful.